# "In cases when" vs. "in cases where"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, when, where

This is one I struggle with from time to time. Which is better?

> - Methodology X is more suitable in cases **where** users' needs are well understood up front.
> - Methodology X is more suitable in cases **when** users' needs are well understood up front.

Is one of these ungrammatical? Or is it purely a matter of personal preference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you use "in cases..." I'd say **where**, because you specified a "location" when you said "is more suitable **in cases** where..."

You could instead use when if you deleted that part so:

> ...is more suitable **when** users' needs...

Comment: Makes quite a bit of sense!

Answer (score 6):

Go with '**where**' because, as @Alenanno states, you have said '*in cases*' which hints at a location, though an abstract one.

You could use '*when*' with a slight reword: '*...suitable at times when...*'.

@Mickeyf 's suggestion (*in which*) would normally be a good substitute but in this particular case it would leave you with a repetition of 'in', which sounds clumsy. This option would fit better if you went with '*...suitable for cases in which...*'.

So, I would say that those are your choices.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't see anything clumsy in using "in cases in which".  But "in which" is inherently a bit stilted.

Comment: It's to do with metaphor, the choice of "where" that is:  cases is a syonym for "situations" here, and a situation *literally* means a the placement of a physical object.  I think that's why "where" feels more natural - it fits our unconscious metaphor.

Comment: Yes, it refers to a metaphorical or abstract location.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence seems to me to be excessively wordy. The tendency to embellish sentences, in the hope of adding an air of authority, should be resisted.

> Methodology X is more suitable in cases where users' needs are well understood up front.

Why not simply say

> Methodology X is more suitable if users' needs are well understood.

Though the context ought also to tell us the specific methodology with which X is being compared.

Answer (score 1):

From [Gartner's modern usage guide](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/in-cases-where), I gather avoid using `cases` altogether.

For example:

> Methodology X is more suitable <s>in cases where</s> **if** users' needs are well understood up front.

Comment: I would vote 50 times if I could. Thanks a lot for this link.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "in which user's needs...". You are referring neither to spatial nor temporal location.

Comment: But then you'd have "in cases in which".