# Are "when", "where" and "of" equally valid after "to include the case..."?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, when, where

What are the rules for the usage of this construct?

For example, suppose you've written a StackExchange answer, and later you decided edit it so that your proposed solution handles an additional case. If you wanted to say "I've edited my answer to include the case..." would you follow that with *when*, *where* or *of*? What are the grammatical conditions?

I know it must have something to do with the following part of your sentence being "situational", "descriptive", etc. but I'm not sure.

Comment: [“In cases when” vs. “In cases where”: does it matter?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21413/in-cases-when-vs-in-cases-where-does-it-matter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as I know, *in the case of* is followed by a noun and never requires a verb. Like this:

> In the case of Abraham Lincoln, ...
>   ... in the case of Lee Harvey Oswald.

On the other hand, *in the case when* and *in the case where* are interchangeable and require a verb with a noun, for example:

> In the case where the application files cannot be found.
>   In the case when the application fails to compile.